# Minikube IP is refusing to connect from browser

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to kubernetes. I am following a tutorial where I need to run a service in a kuberenetes cluster.
After running `minikube start` , I get the below output:

```
>   minikube v1.29.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 (vbox/amd64) ✨  Automatically
> selected the docker driver. Other choices: none, ssh   Using Docker
> driver with root privileges   Starting control plane node minikube
> in cluster minikube   Pulling base image ...   Creating docker
> container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...   Preparing Kubernetes v1.26.1
> on Docker 20.10.23 ...
>     ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
>     ▪ Booting up control plane ...
>     ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...   Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
>     ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5   Verifying Kubernetes components...   Enabled addons:
> default-storageclass, storage-provisioner   Done! kubectl is now
> configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by
> default
```

Then I run `kubectl apply -f client-node-port.yaml`  and `kubectl apply -f client-pod.yaml` respectively.

The client-node-port.yaml  looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-node-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 3001
      nodePort: 31515
  selector: 
    component: web
```

And the client-pod.yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: client-pod
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: dibyajyoti47/multi-client
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
      imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Then I run the command `minikube ip` which gives  `192.168.49.2` as an output.
After that I go to browser with url `192.168.49.2:31515` which gets refused to connect.

Am I missing something here? Please help me resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Note: I am running "Ubuntu 20" in "Oracle VM Virtual box" on "Windows 10" machine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing network type from NAT to Bridge Mode in Virtual box.
Before starting the VM in Oracle virtual box, go to network settings and set network type to Bridge Mode. Then start the VM, it will work as expected.